# Having trouble combining Onsen UI ons-sliding-menu and ons-tabbar

Tags: css, angularjs, cordova, topcoat, onsen-ui

Having trouble combining Onsen UI ons-sliding-menu and ons-tabbar.  I want to have the sliding menu on the top and a icon bar at the bottom.  I have tried the following:

```
<body>  
  <ons-screen>

    <ons-sliding-menu 
      behind-page="menu.html" 
      above-page="navigator1.html">
    </ons-sliding-menu>

<ons-tabbar>
      <ons-tabbar-item
              active="true"
              label="Home"
              icon="home"
              page="navigator1.html"></ons-tabbar-item>

      <ons-tabbar-item
          label="Camera"
              icon="camera"
              page="page2.html"></ons-tabbar-item>

      <ons-tabbar-item
          label="Settings"
              icon="gear"
              page="page3.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
    </ons-tabbar>

  </ons-screen>
```

The slider menu stops working when the obe-tabbar is added.

Is there a more complex example?

Answer (score 4):

You should separate them into their own files.

Here i put tabbar inside sliding menu's above page. You can also put sliding-menu inside tabbar depending on your UI.

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <ons-screen page="sliding_menu.html"></ons-screen>
</body>
```

**sliding_menu.html**

```
<ons-sliding-menu
  behind-page="menu.html" 
  above-page="tabbar.html">
</ons-sliding-menu>
```

**tabbar.html**

```
<ons-tabbar>
  <ons-tabbar-item
          active="true"
          label="Home"
          icon="home"
          page="navigator1.html"></ons-tabbar-item>

  <ons-tabbar-item
      label="Camera"
          icon="camera"
          page="page2.html"></ons-tabbar-item>

  <ons-tabbar-item
      label="Settings"
          icon="gear"
          page="page3.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
</ons-tabbar>
```