# Combining Onsen UI ons-sliding-menu and ons-tabbar

Tags: onsen-ui

I've read this solution: [Having trouble combining Onsen UI ons-sliding-menu and ons-tabbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726481/having-trouble-combining-onsen-ui-ons-sliding-menu-and-ons-tabbar)

But, the question is, when I change the page on right menu, i just lost the tabmenu on boton, so, what I can do programmatic to avoid this?

Comment: Which is the version you use? Please show your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give a same role to slidingMenu and tabbar, i.e. both of them switch a category,
Please see the answer [Sliding menu with Tab bar in Onsen UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588394/sliding-menu-with-tab-bar-in-onsen-ui)